# Parallelogram and side lengths

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, quadrilateral

Using the diagram, find $x$ and $y$ if $ABCD$ is a parallelogram.
[image]

Firstly, we can conclude that $$\measuredangle BAC=\measuredangle ACD=25^\circ \text{ (alternate angles)}$$ Then in triangle $ACD$ we will have $\measuredangle CAD=180^\circ-130^\circ-25^\circ=25^\circ\Rightarrow AD=CD, x=y$. The most obvious thing for me now was to apply the Cosine Rule for $\triangle ACD:$ $$AC^2=AD^2+CD^2-2AD\cdot CD\cos130^\circ\\20^2=2x^2-2x^2\cdot\cos130^\circ$$ Well, $130^\circ$ isn't a "tabular" angle, and we haven't studied how to solve such equations. [WolframApha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=Power%5B20%2C2%5D%3D2Power%5Bx%2C2%5D-2Power%5Bx%2C2%5Dcos130degrees) says that $x\approx 11.034$.
The next thing I tried: Let $DH\perp AC (H\in AC)$. Then $AH=\dfrac12AC=10$ and in $\triangle AHD$ $$\cos25^\circ=\dfrac{AH}{AD}=\dfrac{10}{x}\Rightarrow x=\dfrac{10}{\cos25^\circ}$$ The given answer in my book is $x=y=10\cos25^\circ$. Am I wrong? Thank you!

Comment: @MathLover, do you see where am I wrong? I really don't understand your calculations above.

Comment: @MathLover, I don't think I have.

Comment: Actually you are right!

Comment: What I wrote by law of sines gives the same answer as yours

Comment: By law of sines, $\displaystyle \frac{\sin 50^\circ}{20} = \frac{\sin 25^\circ}{x} \implies x = \frac{10}{\cos 25^\circ}$

Comment: You can take any of the two triangles. Say $\triangle ACD$ $\sin \angle ADC = \sin 130^\circ = \sin 50^\circ$. Other two angles are $25^\circ$.

Comment: @MathLover, thank you! I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

The long answer (Same method):

In $\triangle ABC$ 
$\angle ABC = \angle ADC = 130°$ (Opposite angles of parallelogram are equal) 
$\angle CAB + \angle ACB + \angle ABC = 180°$ 
$\therefore \angle ACB = 25°$ 
As 2 angles are same in $\triangle ABC$, it will be an isosceles triangle. 
$\therefore AB = BC$

CD = y 
AD = x 
$\therefore AB = y$ and $BC = x$ (Opposite sides of parallelogram are equal) 
But AB = BC 
$\therefore AB = BC = CD = AD = x$ 
$\therefore ABCD$ is a rhombus (Parallelogram with equal sides is a rhombus).

Join BD 
In rhombus, the diagonals bisect each other at 90° angle. 
Let the diagonals intersect at point O.

In $\triangle COB$ 
$\angle COB = 90°$ 
$\sin 65 = \frac{10}{x}$
$\therefore x = \frac{10}{\sin 65}$

Answer (score 0):

An idea you might use in the future:

When you said "the most obvious thing ..." it would actually have been been simpler to recognise that, since ACD is isosceles, it splits into two right-angled triangles.
Then you immediately have

$$\cos25^\circ=\dfrac{10}{x}. $$